# Why wouldn't NASA save Orion if Artemis 1 failed

Tags: cost, orion-spacecraft, artemis-program

According to last night's NASA broadcast (and [other sources](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpaceLaunchSystem/comments/oj1b6r/the_artemis1_orion_and_its_launch_abort_system)), the launch abort system (LAS) system for Artemis 1 was inert (except for the apparently separate disposal motor). In the event of an Artemis 1 failure, why wouldn't NASA want to save the [$1 billion](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/artemis-moon-program-cost-delays-nasa-inspector-general/) Orion capsule (not to mention a free LAS test) by having a working LAS?

Even if they were too risk averse to reuse a capsule that went through such an event, surely many of the systems could be reused at a cost far less than loading a LAS with solid fuels?

Comment: They plan to throw away the capsule anyway, except for the seats and a couple of computers. And at the moment, this reuse doesn't actually *save* them money, it *costs* them money because capsule #2 is sitting on the factory floor, waiting for those components for a long time already.